# saturation adjustment is not working for me android

Tags: android, image, image-processing

I tried to adjust saturation using below code, but it is not working properly. I have used saturation value range between 0 to 1.

```
       //deg value range is from 0 to 1.
       public static Bitmap adjustSaturation(Bitmap o, float deg)
    {        
          Bitmap srca = o;
          Bitmap bitmap = srca.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
          for(int x = 0;x < bitmap.getWidth();x++)
              for(int y = 0;y < bitmap.getHeight();y++){
                      int newPixel = saturationChange(bitmap.getPixel(x,y),deg);
                      bitmap.setPixel(x, y, newPixel);
              }

          return bitmap;
    }

             private static int saturationChange(int startpixel,float deg){
          float[] hsv = new float[3];       //array to store HSV values
          Color.colorToHSV(startpixel,hsv); //get original HSV values of pixel
          hsv[1]=hsv[1]+deg;                //add the shift to the HUE of HSV array
          hsv[1]=hsv[1]%1;                //confines hue to values:[0,360]
          return Color.HSVToColor(Color.alpha(startpixel),hsv);
       }
```

Please suggest a solution to this problem.

Comment: What is it doing now? "Not working properly" could mean a lot of things.